# how to open edit popup when click row on kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need your help. Ours customer want open edit popup when click on row. They don't want to see edit button end of the grid's row.

How can I that?

Comment: `onclick="window.open()"` Use google

Comment: Did you use kendo grid before? Have you an example for my issue? My problem is not simple like you said. I use google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in this [thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/wire-popup-to-doubleclick-row-event) you can get default popup editing mode like this

```
$("#grid").delegate("tbody>tr", "dblclick", function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('k-grid-edit-row')) {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").editRow($(this));
    }
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/UrIhU).

Comment: thank you so much, that is the thing what I need exactly.